# PHP ArrayObject inner workings

Tags: php, spl, arrayobject

Where can I find the ArrayObject's complete source code (in PHP)?

What I dont understand is why you can use the "arrow" when add an element to your ArrayObject, for example:

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['arr'] = 'array data';                             
$a->prop = 'prop data';  //here it is
```

You can see `$a->prop = 'prop data';` is used.

Is there any magic method or what was used, and how PHP knows for example that `$a['prop']` and `$a->prop` means the same ? (in this context)

Comment: You always can do this: `public function __set( $key, $val){$this->arr[$key] = $val;}` and the same with getter .)

Comment: It's actually [just written in C](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/spl_array.c?view=markup) although, you could make the same one with pure PHP.

Comment: *(source)* http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/spl/spl_array.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is magic and it can be accomplished directly in PHP. Take look at **Overloading** http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

You can use `__get()` and `__set` in a class to do this. To make objects behave like arrays, you have to implement http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

This is my example code:

```
<?php
class MyArrayObject implements Iterator, ArrayAccess, Countable
{
    /**  Location for overloaded data.  */
    private $_data = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_data)) {
            return $this->_data[$name];
        }

        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error(
            'Undefined property via __get(): ' . $name .
            ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
            ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
            E_USER_NOTICE);
        return null;
    }

    /**  As of PHP 5.1.0  */
    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->_data[$name]);
    }

    /**  As of PHP 5.1.0  */
    public function __unset($name)
    {
        unset($this->_data[$name]);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->_data[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->_data[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->_data[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->_data[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->_data[$offset]) ? $this->_data[$offset] : null;
    }
    public function count(){
        return count($this->_data);
    }
    public function current(){
        return current($this->_data);
    }
    public function next(){
        return next($this->_data);
    }
    public function key(){
        return key($this->_data);
    }
    public function valid(){
        return key($this->_data) !== null;
    }
    public function rewind(){
        reset($this->_data);
    }
}
```

Instead of `current($a)`, `next($a)` use `$a->current()`, `$a->next()`

Comment: You wrote this example now (under 1 min)?:D  Do you know where can i find the exact implementation?

Comment: Actually I stole it from the PHP documentation and edited some parts.

Comment: The exact implementation is not written in PHP, but in C and can be found in the PHP sourcecode. Download it from http://php.net/downloads.php and take a look at `ext/spl/spl_array.c`

Comment: Or you can take a look at the implementation in the repository at http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/spl/spl_array.c?view=log

Comment: Then I have to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php. Hold on a sec, I will edit my post.

Comment: Okay, very good. It's getting clear. The problem was that the docs didn't mentioned the __set, and __get magic methods anywhere , so it was a little bit strange.. And yeah, its inherits from ArrayAccess, so yeah its clear now guys. Thx again.